# Where would I get the base URI In my ServiceStack markdown page?

Tags: servicestack

I am looking to serve an image from my root path test.com/some.png but this markdown page may be displayed on [Post]test.com/Item or [Put]test.com/Item/123 So I am looking for a way to get the base URI to form the image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the literal text `~/` inside a Markdown page gets converted to a virtual path.

This literal is registered on start-up from the global `EndpointHostConfig.MarkdownReplaceTokens` property which is assigned the [appHost.Config.WebHostUrl property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/Formats/MarkdownFormat.cs#L81):

```
this.MarkdownReplaceTokens["~/"] = appHost.Config.WebHostUrl.WithTrailingSlash();
```

Since it's difficult for an ASP.NET framework to determine the url its hosted at (i.e. without a request) you need to specify the preferred url you wan to use in your config. Here's an example from the [servicestack.net/docs/](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/) - ServiceStack's markdown Docs project:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    WebHostUrl = baseUrl,                          //replaces ~/ with Url
    MarkdownBaseType = typeof(CustomMarkdownPage), 
});
```

Otherwise inside your service you can use `base.Request` or `base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>()` to get information about the incoming Request as well as `(HttpRequest)base.Request.OriginalRequest` to get the underlying ASP.NET Request object.

Comment: Looking at the code https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/Formats/MarkdownFormat.cs#L81 it looks like the ~/ replacement only happens in the template not the markdown page?  This is what I currently see using ~/ in my *.md page is not replaced.